# SIP server/provider with PushKit

Tags: ios, sip, pushkit

I develop a SIP app in iOS and I would like to know if anybody have found a sip server that supports PushKit. It might be

- an existing sip provider
- an opensource sip server (eg asterisk) with this capability implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIP server doesn't need to support PushKit, this is something in iOS. There are 2 types of push notifications that the app can recognize and handle differently. 
Through the Apple developers portal you will need to generate a certificate type of Voip Services. Use this and the token while pushing and in iOS register and lookout for these.
This site shows differences between push types: https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip
Apples best practices for VoIP: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

On your SIP server, you will just need to send a push notification on an incoming call. If you use Asterisk you can use AGI so you can perform the push in whichever language. I've always just use APNS but there's a bunch to choose from like AWS, Urban Airship, Onesignal.

Comment: Sure, PushKit is a framework on the client side. I was asking if you know a SIP server that already supports a client with PushKit enabled, ie a sip server with a capability to push notifications instead of keeping a persistent connection between the sip module and the client.

Comment: There isn't at least for Asterisk. It would be very quick to add into AGI on an incoming call. You can use any language so you can quickly download lets say a PHP sdk and get that running. Here is a post with malcomd responding for the same question: http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=92220

Comment: Yes I had same confusion about how to accomplish the sending part from server. So @Chris I need to have a AGL which sends push notification to phones and some changes in dialplan (extension.conf) file right? and Do i need to change any configuration in pjsip projects?

Comment: Basically, you just need to execute some code. If you don't have a full asterisk application and just using extensions.conf you can simply use SYSTEM("sh pushnotification --token APUSHTOKENHERE") and then you can run whatever kind of script you want like shell, node, php, python.
The script itself just has to send a push notification and you can search online and there hundreds of examples per each language

Answer (score 0):

Urbanship confirmed that they would not support voip push in the near future (at the end of 2016). Finally, I found I can just use [houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) to send voip push. From my experience sending voip push and apn push are just the same from our side, e.g. they send to the same apple server, so I guess apple server will differentiate them based on their tokens and give voip push a higher priority.